# Extract attributes from similar nodes in OpenIR

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

The goal of this mission is extract the “href” about the titles of thesis in a search results page of an IR, and make them as a data frame.
This results page is not well structured: title of paper, issue information, authors, and download button are in the same field, only separate by “span”(between “title”, “issue”, and “authors”) and “sup”(inside “authors”).

```
results<-"http://ir.las.ac.cn/handle/12502/8473/browse?type=dateissued"
library(rvest)
resultsource <- read_html(results)
itemLine <- html_node(resultsource, xpath ='//tr[@class="itemLine"]')
# gether labels and values of item metadata in miscTable2
titleLine <- html_nodes(itemLine, xpath ='//span/a[@href][@target]')
titlehref <- xml_attrs(titleLine, "href")
resultstxt <- html_text(titleLine, trim = TRUE)
```

The program above runs without errors, but the “titleLine” has many redundance, and “titlehref” only have a contest as ‘     class 
"itemLine"’ but no URLs at all.
My questions are:

1. How can we locate the href of the paper title accurately? I use a
   second layer of “html_nodes” to save all the target href. However,
   the “href”s which under “sup” label still in the “titleLine”, and
   the “target” too. Can we use “target” attribute for locate the right
   “href” but not let them appears in “titleLine”?
2. How can we locate attributes with complex “value”? in the program
   above, I use “href” only. I have tried to use “xpath style” before
   but no help. I want to use name space to identify the URL of papers,
   but I saw that maybe ns only extract from “xmlns” attribute, and
   could not assignment manually(like `titlehref <-
   xml_attrs(titleLine, "href", ns=”http://ir.las.ac.cn/handle”)`)

How to fit the structure of this IR can get the correct results? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the desired `<span>` target as well as the `<td>`

```
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html("http://ir.las.ac.cn/handle/12502/8473/browse?type=dateissued")

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//tr[@class='itemLine']/td[2]/span[1]/a") %>% 
  html_text()
##  [1] "Data-driven Discovery: A New Era of Exploiting the Literature and Data"                                                                                       
##  [2] "Contents Index to Volume 1"                                                                                                                                   
##  [3] "Topic Detection Based on Weak Tie Analysis: A Case Study of LIS Research"                                                                                     
##  [4] "Open Peer Review in Scientific Publishing: A Web Mining Study of <i>PeerJ</i> Authors and Reviewers"                                                          
##  [5] "Mapping Diversity of Publication Patterns in the Social Sciences and Humanities: An Approach Making Use of Fuzzy Cluster Analysis"                            
##  [6] "Under-reporting of Adverse Events in the Biomedical Literature"                                                                                               
##  [7] "Predictive Characteristics of Co-authorship Networks: Comparing the Unweighted, Weighted, and Bipartite Cases"                                                
##  [8] "International Conference on Scientometrics & Informetrics October16-20, 2017, Wuhan · China"                                                                  
##  [9] "Identification and Analysis of Multi-tasking Product Information Search Sessions with Query Logs"                                                             
## [10] "The 1<sup>st</sup> International Conference on Datadriven Knowledge Discovery: When Data Science Meets Information Science. June 19-22, 2016, Beijing · China"
## [11] "The Power-weakness Ratios (PWR) as a Journal Indicator: Testing the “Tournaments” Metaphor in Citation Impact Studies"                                        
## [12] "Document Type Profiles in <i>Nature, Science</i>, and <i>PNAS</i>: Journal and Country Level"                                                                 
## [13] "Can Automatic Classification Help to Increase Accuracy in Data Collection?"                                                                                   
## [14] "Knowledge Representation in Patient Safety Reporting: An Ontological Approach"                                                                                
## [15] "Information Science Roles in the Emerging Field of Data Science"                                                                                              
## [16] "Data Science Altmetrics"                                                                                                                                      
## [17] "Comparative Study of Trace Metrics between Bibliometrics and Patentometrics"                                                                                  
## [18] "Identifying Scientific Project-generated Data Citation from Full-text Articles: An Investigation of TCGA Data Citation"                                       
## [19] "Mining Related Articles for Automatic Journal Cataloging"                                                                                                     
## [20] "Critical Factors for Personal Cloud Storage Adoption in ChinaCritical Factors for Personal Cloud Storage Adoption in China"
```

The HTML tags in ^^ like "`…" are errors on their end (they appear in the rendered browser view, too). I think someone on their end went too far in XSS prevention.

Comment: It is strange that the answer you post is the earliest, but it appeared last. I learned how to locate one of the similar element in a node from your answer. Thanks a lot. But when I modify it to extract the URLs of papers, the results include another unrelated attribute "target", even I had assign the attribute as "href": itemu<-html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//tr[@class='itemLine']/td[2]/span[1]/a[@href]") %>% 
  html_attrs()
If I move the "[@href]" into fuction "html_attrs()", an error occurs. That means the pipe could not transfer one of the attributes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
library(rvest)
url<-"http://ir.las.ac.cn/handle/12502/8473/browse?type=dateissued"
page<-html_session(url)

# DATA EXTRACTION
title<-html_nodes(page,css="strong") %>% html_text()
title<-title[5:length(title)]
download_link<-html_nodes(page, css= "span:nth-child(7) a+ a") %>% html_attr("href")
issue_information<-html_nodes(page, css= "i") %>% html_text()
authors<-html_nodes(page,css=".itemLine span:nth-child(5)") %>% html_text()

# CONVERT TO DATA FRAME
k<-data.frame(title,download_link,issue_information,authors)
```

Run the code on each page to get the full data frame.

For locating different elements I used "SELECTOR GADGET" chrome add in and then used in the code.

Comment: Excuse me, where can we get further instruction of "CSS selector" used in "xml2" package? Does this technology a general tech in all the web analysis tools and browsers? Thanks a lot.

Comment: People use SELECTOR GADGET more frequently for webscraping. Its available here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en

Comment: Your program works, but not the results I desired exactly. I want to get the URLs of meta data page of those papers, which record in the attribute of the "paper title" node. And these "href"s seems hard to scrap. Thanks for your help.